# How can I list all head node host names on a network?

Tags: networking, hosts, hostname, cluster, nodes

We have multiple clusters available at work. I don't know the names of all of them. How can I get a list of all head nodes available?

Comment: I believe the term "head node" is general enough that it could be used for any clustering technology for any OS. You might want to specify which OS and clustering technology you're talking about, because the instructions are likely to differ by clustering solution.

Comment: @Spiff The OS is Ubuntu on the newest head nodes. It's a lustre file system.